# Symfony2 - Monolog - Level up or down customized logger

Tags: php, symfony, logging, monolog

Using Symfon2 and its Monolog framework to for logging, I am having some trouble.

On the one hand, I have a service configured with my own logger. It is working properly and I get to "info" and "err" messages without problems.

```
services:
  my_logger:
    class: Monolog\Logger
    arguments: [my_info]
    calls:
        - [pushHandler, [@my_log_handler]]

  my_log_handler:
    class: Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler
    arguments: [%kernel.root_dir%/logs/my_info.log, 100]
```

Using the following in the controller causes proper messages to be written
    $this->get('my_logger')->info('info message');
    $this->get('my_logger')->err('error message');

Here comes my question

Once I have placed planty of those `->err` and `->info` logging messages, how I tell the configuration to just write those written through the `err` method?

At the beginning may be I need many information, and for that reason I would write many info messages. But in a while, I may prefer to level up the logging messages through setting the action level to warning or error, avoiding the info logs to be written.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to tweak the level at which your handler is listening. In this case it means changing the `100` to something higher like `400` for errors. So that gives you:

```
  my_log_handler:
    class: Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler
    arguments: [%kernel.root_dir%/logs/my_info.log, 400]
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks!! To be honest, I didn't know what that parameter was for.